# Android Studio code style settings not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I select all my code in Android Studio, then I apply code formatting for example for the piece of code below:

```
public ArrayList<RuleData> listOfActivePromotions()
{
    try
    {
        return RuleData.getRuleData();

    }
    catch (RepositoryException ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogging.getInstance().logException(TAG, ex); Log.e(this.TAG, "error", ex); return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

My code ends up being indented and overlapping other code that it becomes difficult to read. 
I have set my code settings as follows :

[image: Code Style Settings]

I am not sure why it is wrapping the separate code lines like that, this only started recently.
I have tried changing all the setting and still the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Delete your idea file and re-import project it will help to solve your issue